# having trouble with inserting data into mysqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, database, eclipse

hi i am new to android development and need help with inserting my data into a MYSQLite database could someone help me understand the problem thanks
using log cat and this is the error that it gives me

05-02 18:53:05.087: I/Database(331): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table suspect has no column named other
05-02 18:53:05.097: E/Database(331): Error inserting other=8 – 14 nationality= height=8 – 14 age= name= suspect= gender=Male hair=V@N

```
package com.example.sherlock;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Database extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText nametxt;
private Spinner gender;
private Spinner age;
private EditText hairtxt;
private EditText heighttxt;
private EditText nationalitytxt;
private EditText othertxt;
private Spinner suspecttype;
private Button submitbtn;
private Button clearbtn;


//called when activity is created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

nametxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
gender =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender);
age =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.age);
hairtxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.hairtxt);
heighttxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.heighttxt);
nationalitytxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nationalitytxt);
othertxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.othertxt);
suspecttype =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.age);

submitbtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);
submitbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
clearbtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
clearbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){

   if(v.getId ()==R.id.submitbtn){
  String providenametxt = nametxt.getText().toString();
  String providegender = gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String provideage = age.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String providehairtxt = hairtxt.getText().toString();
  String provideheighttxt = heighttxt.getText().toString();
  String providenationalitytxt = nationalitytxt.getText().toString();
  String provideothertxt = othertxt.getText().toString();
  String providesuspecttype = suspecttype.getSelectedItem().toString();


  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
  db.addSuspect(new Suspects( providenametxt, providegender, 
  provideage, providehairtxt,                   
  provideheighttxt, providenationalitytxt, 
  provideothertxt, providesuspecttype));
  //reading all contacts
  Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all Contacts..");
  List<Suspects> suspects = db.getAllSuspects();

  for (Suspects cn : suspects) {
   String log = "Id: "+ cn.getID() +" ,Name: " + cn.getName() 
   +" ,Gender: " +    cn.getGender()  +" ,Age: " + cn.getAge()
   +" ,Hair: " + cn.getHair() +" ,Height: " + cn.getHeight()
   +" ,Nationality: " + cn.getNationality() +" ,Other: " + cn.getOther() 
   +" ,Suspecttype: " + cn.getSuspect();
  //Writing contacts to log
  Log.d("Name: ", log);
   }
   //release from existing UI
   db.close();
  finish();
  }
  }
  }
```

DBAdapter

```
package com.example.sherlock;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_HAIR = "hair";
public static final String KEY_NATIONALITY = "nationality";
public static final String KEY_SUSPECT = "suspect";
public static final String KEY_OTHER = "other";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SuspectDB";
private static final String TABLE_SUSPECTS = "suspect";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


 public DBAdapter(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

//create tables
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_Suspects_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SUSPECTS + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_HEIGHT + "TEXT,"  
                + KEY_AGE + "TEXT," 
                + KEY_HAIR + "TEXT," 
                + KEY_NATIONALITY + "TEXT,"
                + KEY_SUSPECT + "TEXT," 
                + KEY_OTHER + "TEXT" +")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_Suspects_TABLE);
    }
// Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SUSPECTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new suspect
    void addSuspect(Suspects suspects) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, suspects.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, suspects.getGender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, suspects.getHeight());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, suspects.getAge());
        values.put(KEY_HAIR, suspects.getHair());
        values.put(KEY_NATIONALITY, suspects.getNationality());
        values.put(KEY_SUSPECT, suspects.getSuspect());
        values.put(KEY_OTHER, suspects.getOther());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_SUSPECTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Suspects getSuspect(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUSPECTS, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_GENDER, KEY_HEIGHT,
   KEY_AGE, KEY_HAIR,KEY_NATIONALITY,KEY_SUSPECT,
  KEY_OTHER }, KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Suspects suspect = new Suspects(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6),
                cursor.getString(7),
                cursor.getString(8));
        // return suspect
        return suspect;
    }

    // Getting All suspects
    public List<Suspects> getAllSuspects() {
        List<Suspects> SuspectsList = new ArrayList<Suspects>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SUSPECTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Suspects suspect = new Suspects();
                suspect.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                suspect.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                suspect.setGender(cursor.getString(2));
                suspect.setHeight(cursor.getString(3));
                suspect.setAge(cursor.getString(4));
                suspect.setHair(cursor.getString(5));
                suspect.setNationality(cursor.getString(6));
                suspect.setSuspect(cursor.getString(7));
                suspect.setOther(cursor.getString(8));

       // Adding contact to list
                SuspectsList.add(suspect);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Suspect list
        return SuspectsList;
    }

    // Updating single Suspect
    public int updateSuspects(Suspects suspect) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, suspect.getName());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, suspect.getGender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, suspect.getHeight());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, suspect.getAge());
        values.put(KEY_HAIR, suspect.getHair());
        values.put(KEY_NATIONALITY, suspect.getNationality());
        values.put(KEY_SUSPECT, suspect.getSuspect());
        values.put(KEY_OTHER, suspect.getOther());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_SUSPECTS, values, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(suspect.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single suspect
    public void deleteSuspect(Suspects suspect) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SUSPECTS, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(suspect.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting suspect Count
    public int getSuspectsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SUSPECTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }    
}
```

Comment: SQLite code 1 is "SQL error or missing database."  99 times out of 100, you get that error because of malformed SQL statements, often when you don't enclose strings in single quotes or make other small syntax errors in your SQL.  Why don't you dump the line of SQL you're trying to write to LogCat?  I think the solution will be fairly obvious at that point.

Comment: can you add the code for the DBAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

In table suspect has no column named other. I think you should delete the database file and run you app again or update the database.

Comment: It is always a better approach to go through your code once, rather than making assumptions.

Comment: used logcat to debug the error and but no column can be created neither other or suspect if i remove others

Comment: [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69131649/sherlock%20(2).zip

this is a link to the code i'm having problems with

Answer (score 0):

fixed the error had to rename the database to suspectsDB